# C# Collection classes - yes or no

Tags: c#, class, collections

I'm a relative newbie to C#, although I am a competent programmer, and I confess that I am totally confused as to whether or not it is a good idea to write custom collection classes. So many people seem to say "don't", yet there is a whole set of base classes for it in C#.

Here is my specific case. I have a timetable application. As part of that, I have a service class, and the service class contains collections of things service-y, such as route links. A route link is itself a custom class:

```
public class Service
{
  public RouteLinks RL;    // A collection of RouteLink types
  ...
}

public class RouteLink
{
    public string FirstStopRef;
    public string LastStopRef;
    public Tracks RouteTrack;    // Another collection, this time of Track types
}
```

So far I have looked at using Dictionary as the type for RouteLinks, because I need to be able to reference them. This is fine in principle. However, the process of adding a RouteLink to the RouteLinks collection involves checking to see whether it is already there, or whether it extends and existing route link, or... And for that, I need a custom Add function.

So why is is such bad practice to create custom collection classes? Why shouldn't I just inherit CollectionBase or DictionaryBase?

I should perhaps add that I am transferring this code from VBA [please don't shoot me :)] and there I HAD to implement custom collections.

Comment: I don't normally create custom collections, but I can see your point and would like to see other people's opinions on this. Extension methods perhaps?

Comment: Even if you do choose to implement a collection - don't do it from scratch. Instead, wrap an internal standard collection.

Comment: My first attempt would be to write an extension method "MyAdd()" for your dictionary. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: `So why is is such bad practice to create custom collection classes?`

In and of itself, it is not. That's why they're not sealed. 

It's only bad practice if you inherit from collection classes to implement a business object - as opposed to a (possibly improved) *mechanism*.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

- Eric Lippert's answer especially. The distinction between a mechanism and a business object nails it down.

Comment: @KonradMorawski, oh yeah, I remember this article. Good one.

Comment: `So far I have looked at using Dictionary as the type for RouteLinks, because I need to be able to reference them.` - You can reference any type, `Dictionary` is not different.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Thank - that's certainly an informative answer, and there were other good nuggets in the comments as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `RouteLinks` be a collection type, an easy solution would be to just define another class, let's say `RouteLinksRepository`. This class will contain a `List<RouteLink>` and the `AddRoute(RouteLink)` functionality as well as any other custom logic for interacting with this collection of `RouteLink` objects. Your service class will then just contain an instance of this repository class.

```
public class Service
{
  public RouteLinksRepository RL;    // A collection of RouteLink types
  // ...
}

public class RouteLinksRepository
{
    public List<RouteLink> RouteLinks;
    public bool AddRoute(RouteLink linkToAdd)
    {
        //Custom logic on whether or not to add link
    }
    //Your other logic for the class

}

public class RouteLink
{
    public string FirstStopRef;
    public string LastStopRef;
    public Tracks RouteTrack;    // Another collection, this time of Track types
}
```

Comment: "Is-implemented-in-terms-of". Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the only need is to check on double entries, a HashSet will do (implement a GetHash and Equals). However I guess you are trying to save a route. A route has a order, which means you have a order and List<> garantees the order. Make the collection objects private to hide the implementation.

```
public class Service
{
  private List<RouteLink> RL;    // A collection of RouteLink types
  ...
}

public class RouteLink
{
    public string FirstStopRef;
    public string LastStopRef;
    private List<Track> Tracks;    // Another collection, this time of Track types
}
```

Comment: It's rather more than just checking on double entries - I simplified it greatly for the question. But thanks, will have to read up more about HashSet as I can see that it might be useful in other use cases.

Comment: @StuartR143 bear in mind that implementing your own collection class can be tricky to get it right. There's a few important caveats to bear in mind, such as thread-safety. There's a rich ecosystem of opensource .NET projects so if you need some enhanced functionality that standard .NET libraries don't give you, I'd take a look at ready-made options such as http://www.itu.dk/research/c5 before snapping out my own solutions.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Thanks - another interesting link. Given what I read in the article you linked to in my OP, I think that I am looking at fairly standard collections, and that what I mostly need to do is to provide a customised Add method for a particular need. So I am writing business objects, rather than mechanisms, to borrow your terminology. 

Lots of incredibly useful pointers to think about.